# Distinct count of values in a column if two other cells match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Struggling a bit with array formula's to count distinct values in one column, in the rows where two other cells match. Sorry if I can't explain any better. Best is to show you the formula I created and provide some sample data:

**Sheet 1**

```
Column A      Column B  
Period 101    Code X
Period 309    Code Y
Period 101    Code Y
Period 101    Code Z
Period 404    Code Y
Period 101    Code X
Period 101    Code X
Period 404    Code X
Period 404    Code Z
```

**Sheet 2**

```
Column A      Column B (where the formula should be)
Code X        2
Code Y        3
Code Z        2
```

Basically I want to count the distinct values in Sheet 1 column A, only where the value in Sheet 1 column B matches the value in sheet 2 column A. I have provided the expected outcome for the three code values.

I have tried with the following formula, but I am unable to count distinct values in another column where the two cells match:

```
{=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(C5:C11=G5,MATCH(B5:B11,B5:B11,0)),ROW(B5:B11)-ROW(B5)+1)>0))}
```

Please ignore the rows and columns used in the formula, also the values in Column A and B on sheet 1 both occur multiple times, but the values in column one on sheet 2 only occur once.

I am curious how someone would solve this one. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula doesn't match your sample data but let's assume the below:

[image]

Formula in `H5`:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(C$5:C$13=G5,MATCH(B$5:B$13,B$5:B$13,0)),ROW(B$5:B$13)-ROW(B$5)+1)>0))
```

Entered as array through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and drag down

Notice the semi-absolute cell references (you used relative ones) + how my ranges are larger than yours (you looked from `C5:C11` only)

Comment: Thank you JvdV, indeed I mentioned the references where wrong. Next time I will update them accordingly. I did not know I could use references to a third column, but it is clear now. Cheers!

Comment: Can you extend this to match a code in column D, too?

Answer (score 2):

Caveat: This answer is unlikely to be useful to the OP, as these techniques are as yet only available to [Excel Insiders](https://insider.office.com/en-nz/)

But once these new features are available to the main stream they will be a game changer.

This uses the new [Dynamic Array](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dynamic-arrays-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531) feature coming to Excel soon.

To create the list of unique values from Column B, place this formula in a *single cell*.  Excel will "Spill" into as many rows as needed to return the unique list of values from Column `B`. For example, I have used cell `E2`

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER($B:$B,$B:$B<>""))
```

Now, place this formula in a the next adjacent cell, I've used `F2`

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER($A:$A,$B:$B=$E$2)))
```

Again, you only need to put this formula in *one* cell, no need to copy down.  Excel will  "Spill" the result into as many cells as needed, to match column `E`.

[image]